# I am using appium.app on mac how to open more than one session to run with different ports

Tags: ios, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

I want to run the appium with different ports i am using appium.app on mac desktop.how to run with different ports any ideas..?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean to run appium with different ports? In case you're using the app, you set the port before you start the server.

In case you meant to run multiple appium sessions with different ports, I've installed appium using npm and then started my servers from command line

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about attaching more than one device and then executing the scripts in parallel on all devices like the selenium grid.

You can go through this [link](http://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/grid/), which is appum's official documentation for setting up selenium grid for mobile automation.